# Testing with a session data to display a photo in a blade page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session

I want to test "sexe" to display a photo. I use the session but nothing happens.

That's the controller:

```
   public function store () {

    request()->validate([


            'username'=>['required'],
            'sexe'=>['required'] ,
            'role'=>['required'] ,
    ]);

    $enfant= new enfant();


    $enfant->username=request('username');
    $enfant->role=request('role');
    $enfant->sexe=request('sexe'); 
    $enfant->parent_id=Auth::user()->id;

    $enfant->save();
    $sexe = session()->get( 'sexe' );
    return redirect ('/themes', compact('enfants'))->with([ 'sexe' => $sexe ]);

}
```

and that's the view

```
  {{ session()->get( 'sexe' ) }}
           @if ( 'sexe'=='f' )
           <img src="images/avatarF.png" class="profile" style="width: 160px ; height: 160px;">
          @endif 
           @if ( 'sexe'=='h' )
           <img src="images/avatarG.png" class="profile" style="width: 1600px ; height: 160px; margin-top: 0px;">
          @endif
```

Comment: where is the populate sexe session ?

Comment: i don't know how to use session !! that's why i'm asking

Comment: `'sexe'=='f'` & `'sexe'=='h'` will never be `true`. So no image tag will be displayed.

Comment: what can i do then ?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
$sexe = session()->get( 'sexe' );
```

instead of

```
session()->put('sexe', request('sexe'));
```

in your view

```
  @if ( session()->get( 'sexe' )=='f' )
           <img src="images/avatarF.png" class="profile" style="width: 160px ; height: 160px;">
          @endif 
           @if ( session()->get( 'sexe' )=='h' )
           <img src="images/avatarG.png" class="profile" style="width: 1600px ; height: 160px; margin-top: 0px;">
          @endif
```

Comment: I had this error:     Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must be of the type integer, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\kismApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php on line 203

Comment: please remove ->with([ 'sexe' => $sexe ]);

Comment: this is the route   Route::get('/themes/{sexe}', function () {
    return view('themes');
    });

Comment: this is so wrong where is your controller no closure. like
Route::get('themes', 'YourController@store');

Comment: themes is a simple page what could i do in its controller

Comment: because you have controller. also your route is exactly wrong.

Comment: how can i fix it

Comment: i told you first of all in your routes.php Route::get('themes', 'YourController@store');  after that look my response.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store () {
    request()->validate([

            'username'=>['required'],
            'sexe'=>['required'] ,
            'role'=>['required'] ,
    ]);

    $enfant= new enfant();


    $enfant->username=request('username');
    $enfant->role=request('role');
    $enfant->sexe=request('sexe'); 
    $enfant->parent_id=Auth::user()->id;

    $enfant->save();
    return redirect ('/themes', compact('enfants'))->with([ 'sexe' => $request()->sexe ]);

}
```

and that's the view

```
 @if ( session('sexe') == 'f' )
           <img src="images/avatarF.png" class="profile" style="width: 160px ; height: 160px;">
 @elseif( session('sexe') == 'h' )
           <img src="images/avatarG.png" class="profile" style="width: 1600px ; height: 160px; margin-top: 0px;">
@endif
```

Comment: how can you use the session in the view while u didn't use it in the controller ?